# SAS Management Console, Exited with exit code 116, ERROR: Unrecognized SAS option name

Tags: sas

I'm using sas management console to schedule job. The job end almost immediately and the error i recieve by email is :

Exited with exit code 116.

Resource usage summary:

```
CPU time :               0.28 sec.
Max Memory :             14 MB
Total Requested Memory : -
Delta Memory :           -
(Delta: the difference between total requested memory and actual max usage.)
```

The output (if any) follows:

ERROR: Unrecognized SAS option name LOGU+00A0/FILEPATH/LOGNAME.LOG.
ERROR: (SASXKRIN): KERNEL RESOURCE INITIALIZATION FAILED.
ERROR: Unable to initialize the SAS kernel.

Any ideas what the issue could be ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 00A0 is a non-breaking space - you might have one where you think you have a space character (did you paste something from the web, for example)?

Comment: Looks like an error in the command used to launch SAS.  I would talk with your SAS admin. Typically you as a developer are not responsible for this command string, it is generated for you.